# Swagger not generating model for object wrapped by IActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

With the following code, Swaggger UI shows the RegistrationInfo model but not the UserInfo model.

How do I get that to generate?

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api")]

public class UserController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost("RegisterUser")]
    public  IActionResult RegisterUser([FromBody] RegistrationInfo info)
    {
        UserInfo data =    UserData.RegisterUser(info);
        if (data != null)
        {
            return Ok(data);
        }
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888207/swaggerui-not-displaying-model-schema

Comment: Why the link   ''''       ?

Comment: The problem is similar , but not the same. I thought it may have a clue.

Comment: What happens when you set a break point at `UserInfo data = UserData.RegisterUser(info);` Is `data != null`?

Comment: why do you ask? the code is not run during the ui generation.

Comment: I was just curious. Is UserInfo a property of the RegistrationInfo Model? I imagine it is from the example above, but just thought I'd ask.

Comment: I updated the question to give more information. the structure of UserInfo is not relevant

Comment: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/777

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use the `ProducesResponseType` attribute.  Change your controller to this:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(UserInfo), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [HttpPost("RegisterUser")]
    public IActionResult RegisterUser([FromBody] RegistrationInfo info)
    {
        UserInfo data = UserData.RegisterUser(info);
        if (data != null)
        {
            return Ok(data);
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1).